# Html external script not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have create a external script call script.js save in js folder. However i don't know why it is not working. Therefore, I have tried put the  into the html file and it work fine. So I think it is the problem of missing something in  or i don't know.

It is my html code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <title>...........</title>

    <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script  src="js/script.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
  <body>
       <button class="button">show</button>
        <p>yo</p>
   </body>
```

JQuery

```
        $(".button").click(function(){
    $("p").toggle();
});
```

Comment: does jquery need to go first?

Comment: I could speculate, but without seeing the JS code, I can't know what the problem is. Look at your JavaScript error console. What does it say?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure jquery is loaded first:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
```

I'd also move this to just before the closing `</body>` tag in your HTML.

And then check where the JS folder is relative to the HTML file you've written. Currently, the folder would need to be at the same level in the directory structure as the HTML file.

Answer (score 0):

Inside your script, use `window.onload`. The script might be firing before the DOM has actually finished loading.

You might also want to put jQuery on top so that it finishes loading before any possible jQuery code in your script fires.

Answer (score 0):

Try loading JS in the footer.

> You need the elements to be present in DOM before you can select them.
>   Moreover including external js files at the bottom of your page, gives priority of your HTTP requests to the visual display that will be presented to the client instead of to the logic of interaction or dynamics;

this is the usual behavior you'd want.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jquery in your JavaScript code please put them in this order

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>...........</title>

<link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script     src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script  src="js/script.js"></script>

</head>
```

If that is not the case can you post the error in the console (using chrome press f12 to see the errors in the console)

Other thing you can check, the js folder is in same directory where your html page is?

let us know

Comment: is it the problem of xampp?

Comment: @yoadle is this directory same directory where your html is located?